# What does the Google Translate shield icon mean?

Tags: google-translate

What does the Google Translate shield icon mean? How can a word be protected?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not "protection" but **validation**. Google Translate allows users to participate in kind off validation program which is able to improve the complexity of translation AI algorithm. This translation AI algorithm kicks in whenever you try to translate phrase or sentence and its purpose is to improve translation experience and make it more "smart-like" because ordinary "word-for-word" (robotic) dictionary translation is already on its edge eg. out-dated. In other words, the validation icon (should) signalise that translation (between two completely different languages which have no common ground nor logic, history etc.) is solid.

[image: 1]

**[http://translate.google.com/community](http://translate.google.com/community?source=mfooter)**

Comment: There is an additional, clickable, shield icon, different from the one highlighted in the original question, that lacks a tooltip but that seems to be a way to "upvote" a translation.  Perhaps someone could add an answer regarding this clickable one as well (since the same question brought me here for this other variant.)  https://snipboard.io/8JdVSB.jpg  (I'd question google's judgement if they're using it to justify the validation mark like the community link, since it's so easy to click.)